# If I have a for loop that uses Obj-C blocks, how can I identify the last iteration?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I have a simple class that exposes a method that makes multiple server calls to fetch object data for a list of object IDs. That method enumerates through the list of object IDs and makes individual server calls, shown below...

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)fetchObjectsFromServerWithObjectIDs:(NSArray*)objectIDs {

    typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
    for(NSString *objectID in objectIDs) {
        [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{
            if(objectID == [objectIDs lastObject]) {  //<---will this work?
                [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)fetchObjectDataForObjectID:(NSString*)objectID
                  withSuccessBlock:(void (^)())successBlock {

    void (^successWrapperBlock)(void) = ^{

        //Some processing of returned data is done here

        if(successBlock) {
            successBlock();
        }
    };

    [HTTPClient fetchObjectDataWithObjectID:objectID
                            withSuccessBlock:successWrapperBlock
                                failureBlock:nil];
}

@end
```

...I'm trying to figure out the best way to check if the last `successBlock` is being executed so I can tell the delegate it's finished fetching the data. I have a comment in the code "<---Will this work?" marking the statement that's doing the check, but it doesn't feel safe to me since the block is asynchronous and `if(objectID == [objectIDs lastObject])` could be true when the first successBock if executed.

How can I determine when the last `successBlock` is being executed? Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Is your concern that by the time the success blocks are called, the `objectIDs` array could have been modified?

Comment: There might be a problem. It seems to me that there is no guarantee that the last fetched object will be the last object in the loop will be the last object to finish fetching (fetching is done asynchronously, right?). So even if you manage to do what you want, there is a risk of calling `finishedFetching` before the fetching is actually finished.

Comment: ChrisH's answer deals with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer comparison (`objectID == [objectIDs lastObject]`) is alright here as you will get the same objects *if the array is not modified*. If you are concerned that `objectIDs` might get modified (e.g. that it might actually be a mutable array and get modified on another thread or through side effects like notifications along the way), the best protection would be to copy the array right at the beginning:

```
- (void)fetchObjectsFromServerWithObjectIDs:(NSArray*)objectIDs {

    typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
    NSArray *copiedIDs = [objectIDs copy];

    for(NSString *objectID in copiedIDs) {
        [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{
            if(objectID == [copiedIDs lastObject]) {
                [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

There are now two ways to call the delegate:

1. Call it once the *last fetch has finished.*
2. Or call it once the *fetch for the last object has finished*, even if other fetch requests are in progress.

So you can:

- Use a counter like @ChrisH proposed. This will call the delegate after the very last fetch has finished, no matter in which order they were processed.
- Use the pointer comparison. This will call the delegate after the fetch for *lastObject* has finished.

  - For this, I think there's a minor optimization you can do. As it is, it has the downside that it captures the array in the block and invokes an unnecessary method call every time the block is called. Instead, you can save the last object in an variable, so that the last object instead of the whole array is captured by the block. Note that capturing the array by the block doesn't do any harm. It might just defer freeing some memory.

So you could do (@ChrisH's version plus `copy`):

```
- (void)fetchObjectsFromServerWithObjectIDs:(NSArray*)objectIDs {

    typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
    NSArray *copiedIDs = [objectIDs copy];
    __block NSUInteger count = [copiedIDs count];

    for(NSString *objectID in copiedIDs) {
        [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{
            if(--count == 0) {
                [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

or:

```
- (void)fetchObjectsFromServerWithObjectIDs:(NSArray*)objectIDs {

    typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
    NSArray *copiedIDs = [objectIDs copy];
    id lastObject = [copiedID lastObject];

    for(NSString *objectID in copiedIDs) {
        [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{
            if(objectID == lastObject) {
                [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely the `lastObject` comparison will only work if the async methods end in the same order in which they were started though?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've handled the same situation in the past:

```
- (void)fetchObjectsFromServerWithObjectIDs:(NSArray*)objectIDs {

    typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;

    __block int c = [objectIDs count];

    for (NSString *objectID in objectIDs) {

        [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{

            if (--c == 0) {
                [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
            }

        }];
    }
}
```

It assumes that the array isn't going to be modified during iteration, which I would infer in this case as the object being passed is an immutable array.

Comment: That's right, but is `--c` an atomic operation for `int` in Objective-C? I don't remember. `c=c-1;` id definitely not. If `--c` is not an atomic operation, then this code requires synchronization of access to the `c` variable via a mutex, lock or something like that. Otherwise a very rare and hard-to-catch bugs might occur (sometimes `finishedFetching` won't get called).

Comment: You need to use `__block int c` here, as the block needs to modify the variable.

Comment: @FreeNickname: If the delegate calls all happen on the same thread no synchronization is necessary. If that is not guaranteed, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your concern is that the `objectIDs` array could have fewer or more elements by the time the completion blocks are executed, you could do something like this:

```
typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
id last = [objectIDs lastObject];
for(NSString *objectID in objectIDs) {
    [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{
        if(objectID == last) {
            [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
        }
    }];
}
```

Or use a regular `for` loop:

```
typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
NSUInteger count = objectIDs.count;
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString *objectID = objectIDs[i];
    [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:^{
        if(i == count - 1) {
            [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching]; 
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to count the number of completions.

The slightly harder part is how you count them. If there is no possibility whatsoever of two or more success blocks executing concurrently then you can use a simple `int` variable, see the solution by @ChrisH.

If there is the slightest possibility that two or more success blocks may execute concurrently then you need to count in a thread-safe manner. There a many ways to do this, here is one which uses GCD as you are already using it.

GCD provides *dispatch sources* which schedule a handler every time an *event* occurs. One of these dispatch sources is a simple thread-safe counter which schedules a handler every time the counter changes.

*[All code entered directly into answer, expect typos!]*

Before your `for` loop create a dispatch source:

dispatch_source_t counter = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD, 0, 0, some_queue);

For `some_queue` pass any suitable dispatch queue you have, or you can use `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Now you need to specify the handler, this will test if the counter has reached the size of your array:

```
NSUInteger maxCount = objectIDs.count; // number of items to process
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(counter, ^{
                                              if (dispatch_source_get_data(counter) == maxCount)
                                                [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching];
                                            }
                                 );
```

Every time the counter changes the handler is scheduled, in turn it obtains the current value and checks if you've reached the limit and if so informs your delegate.

Now in your success block you just need to increment your counter, you do this by "merging" the `1` with the counter:

```
dispatch_source_merge_data(counter, 1);
```

Provided you are using ARC on 10.8+ there is no need to release `counter`, if you're not you'll need to call `dispatch_release` at a suitable point. Also reference cycles, if any, are left as an exercise ;-)

The complete code:

```
- (void)fetchObjectsFromServerWithObjectIDs:(NSArray*)objectIDs
{
   dispatch_source_t counter = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD, 0, 0, some_queue);

   NSUInteger maxCount = objectIDs.count; // number of items to process
   dispatch_source_set_event_handler(counter,
                                     ^{
                                         if (dispatch_source_get_data(counter) == maxCount)
                                            [blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching];
                                      });

   typeof(self) __weak blockSelf = self;
   for(NSString *objectID in objectIDs)
   {
      [self fetchObjectDataForObjectID:objectID withSuccessBlock:
       ^{
          dispatch_source_merge_data(counter, 1);
        }];
   }
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't want to catch *the completion of a specific (last in the array) block*, but you want to catch *the completion of all blocks*.

If that's the case, this thing you want sounds awfully similar to operations. `NSOperation` builds on top of GCD but with the ability to add dependencies to or cancel operations.

In your case, I would create and schedule operations for each of IDs. Such an operation would call `fetchObjectDataForObjectID` but not mark itself finished until a success block is called. I would also schedule an operation

```
NSOperation *lastOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [delegate finishedFetching];
}]
```

that is dependent upon completion of those. `lastOp` will be thus executed by the system after all fetching operations have been completed.

I see a lot of questions regarding GCD on Stack Overflow, and surprisingly few answers mention `NSOperation`.  GCD is a purely C stuff, which, imho, should be used without an Objective-C wrapper only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply put the `[blockSelf.delegate finishedFetching];` outside of the for loop so it will execute after the last item? It doesn't look like it needs to be in there.

Comment: Alternately you could simply change your loop to an integer based loop, and use [objectIDs objectAtIndex:] and [objectIDs count] to check the location within objectIDs.

Comment: If you did that the delegate method would fire before any/all of the asynchronous methods in the for loop had finished.